# Not able to change Referrer Policy in Sitecore SXA Site

Tags: sxa, security

We have been trying to change Referrer Policy to 'no-referrer' but no luck. Below are the following approaches we followed for quick verification:

1. Adding the following tag in head section of SXALayout.cshtml

[image]

2. Adding the meta tag in one of the HTML Snippet item under Settings -> HTML Snippets

[image]

Comment: I would say option 1 should never ever be done. Ever. Option two doesn't appear to be correct either. Look into adding custom HTML to the meta data partial design. Please post your solution once you get it working.

Comment: @MichaelWest, it worked. Thanks a lot. Is there a way, that we can validate referer header with SXA OOB features. Kindly let me know

Comment: Great. Please answer your own question. Later you can mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It started working by using Custom Html component (datasource - HTML Snippet) of Metadata partial design. Thanks a lot @MichaelWest